# Start service from the same activity in android

Tags: android

I have a class which extend Intent service. I want to start service from this activity but I get erroor:

```
    Intent msgIntent = new Intent();
    msgIntent.setClass(testActivity, testActivity.class);
    startService(msgIntent);

07-15 11:53:33.030: E/AndroidRuntime(28989): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 11:53:33.030: E/AndroidRuntime(28989):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
```

How can I start service from the same activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent msgIntent = new Intent(YourClass.this, TestService.class);
startService(msgIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are calling startService with testActivity, which is an activity, not a service.

try like that:

```
Intent msgIntent = new Intent(this, yourIntentService.class);
startService(msgIntent);
```